# Command problom VB

Tags: vb.net, cmd

So, I am making a console in VB.net. I decided to use, in a Lua type fashion, a sub string way. However, when doing this, if I type something that is not a command, then it will crash with the error: "Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
        Dim cmd As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim l As Integer = Len(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim param As String
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            '0 Param command
            If cmd = "script" Then
                Script.Show()
                TextBox2.Text = ""

                'Trying to avoide error "Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string." 
            ElseIf Not cmd.Substring(0, 5) = "echo;" Or Not cmd.Substring(0, 9) = "download;" Then
                Return

                '1 Param cmd
            ElseIf cmd.Substring(0, 5) = "echo;" Then
                param = cmd.Substring(5)
                Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + param
                TextBox2.Text = ""

                '2 Param cmd
            ElseIf cmd.Substring(0, 9) = "download;" Then
                param = cmd.Substring(9)
                Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + param.Substring(0, param.IndexOf(";"c)) + param.Substring(param.IndexOf(";"c) + 1)
                TextBox2.Text = ""

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot try to get a substring from locations that are not inside the string.
However instead of trying to get a substring you could use a simpler approach that avoid also the first check on the input text

```
    If cmd = "script" Then
       .....
    ElseIf cmd.StartsWith("echo;") Then
         .....
    ElseIf cmd.StartsWith("download;") Then
         ....
    Else
         Return
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.